# Parsing technique to list all available tokens at any point during a parse

Tags: python, parsing, command-line-interface

I'm wondering if I can represent CLI prompts using a CFG or PEG inspired grammar; for instance, to auto-generate a setup-wizard or survey. In order to achieve this, the parser has to prompt the user for each next input token given what they have already entered.  Example:

```
customer_info -> "My name is " name_expression " and I'm " %age " years old."
name_expression -> %name %name
                 | %name
```

`name_expression` allows you to enter first and last name, or simply a single name. The string constants would be auto-filled by the prompt. This spec would compile the following example experience for a hypothetical user:

```
My name is (enter %name):
>> john
My name is john (1 for "%lastname", 2 for " and I'm "):
>> 2
My name is john and I'm (enter a number):
>> 39
My name is john and I'm [39] years old.
Prompt complete, exiting.
```

I've read a short amount about "inverse parsers", the idea being that during an interactive dialog, all your potential responses are laid out at each step of the conversation *(think RPG-style video game conversation with an NPC)*. Information about this technique seems to be scarce online and I'm not sure it would do what I want entirely.

I've looked into Earley parsers, predictive LL parsers, and some others, but learning each and every one of these candidates just to find out if it is suitable for this case seems unreasonable. My question is, what kind of parsing technique would best allow me to prompt the user for a list of valid tokens given an incomplete input sentence?

Though I'm comfortable with recursive descent parsing and using various parser generators, I've only studied the material for about a year, so pardon my ignorance.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This technique already exists in [LRSTAR](http://lrstar.tech) and I think it's built into ANTLR and Bison/Yacc generated parsers.  It gets activated when an error is encountered in the input.  Then it lists all expected valid tokens.

Some people call it auto-complete or sentence-completion.  It's rarely used for the purpose you are asking about.  However, it's doable with a modified parser. The parser would have to generate the questions, "My first name is" then read the expected token, "<first_name>" from the user.

It's really a simplification of what a parser can do.  Using an LR parser for something this simple is overkill.

The grammar might look like this:

```
Goal      -> Questions <eof>
Questions -> FirstName LastName Street City State Zipcode Age
FirstName -> first name <first_name>
LastName  -> last name <last_name>
Street    -> street <street>
City      -> city <city>
State     -> state <state>
Zipcode   -> zipcode <zipcode>
Age       -> age <age>
```

It's a valid way to automate the creation of questionaires. The parser would generate the words that are not in angled brackets and ask the user to input the variable information.  Or just put the angled bracket words in the grammar, to avoid the redundancy and ask the user for <first_name>, <last_name>, etc.

The best and most reliable method would be creating a Canonical LR(1) parser. 
This kind of parser has all the expected token in every state.  No need to look at other states via default reductions.  As long as your grammar is not huge, you should try a CLR(1) parser.

[LRSTAR](http://lrstar.tech) can generate a CLR(1) parser which already has code builtin to list the expected tokens.

Comment: Helpful answer, but I think that LR (or LL) is not overkill. The full breadth of parsing is at play here, specifically in recursive questionnaires. For instance, in an inventory setup wizard, you have to add an arbitrary number of items, and depending on the type of item, you might have different subsequent questions. Such a parser is trivial if you can avoid productions with multiple derivations (e.g. `item-> name | string_literal`).  But it's that bar operator `|` that's begs the questions "how do I go down the correct path?", and "which parsing technique can offer the best solution?".

Comment: I should add that having a nonterminal with multiple productions is only tricky when they contain other nonterminals. My example above is easy to solve, `item -> name | string_lit`... but what if it's `item -> name item_details | name item_expression`.  What `item_details` and `item_expression` contain can be arbitrary, and they can even have a common prefix. Figuring out how to solve this problem is where I got truly stuck and thought maybe someone has solved this before?

Comment: That is automatically solved in the state machine created by the parser generator.

Comment: LRSTAR is at https://sourceforge.net/projects/lrstar/

Answer (score 1):

Any left-to-right parsing scheme which requires no more than one lookahead token would work fine, provided that the language can be parsed with that scheme. Table-driven implementations are probably easier to work with, provided that the parsing tables are accessible and documented (not the case for most parser generators, unfortunately), but you could use any blackbox parser with a "push" interface and a copyable state, by simply cyclng through all possible token types and recording which ones don't produce errors.

The prediction logic is easier with an LL(1) grammar than with an LR(1) grammar, because the LL parser state is always a unique item. LR parser states are often the union of several items, so it might not be totally obvious how to describe the current parsing context. On the other hand, LR parsers can handle a larger set of grammars.